# Analysis server has terminated (Android studio). How to fix?

Tags: android-studio

I ran into a problem: Analysis detector has terminated. On a macOS with an intel processor. I searched a lot for a solution, but in the end none came up, if anyone knows how to solve this problem - write, I will be grateful.

I was looking for solutions on YouTube, on the Internet, but I didn't really find anything